# css hover styles and iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, mobile

I'm working on a web application where you can select things from a series of buttons. The style of these buttons change when you're hovering over them. I wrapped this style in an `@media` query so that there is no hover styling on mobile: `@media not all and (pointer: coarse)`.

I tested using Chrome developer tools, which allows you to see the mobile display of a website when on desktop, and things worked there. After deploying my changes someone looking at it on their phone complained that they could no longer deselect buttons. However, after updating to the latest iOS(13 I believe) the issue was resolved for him. I've checked on my personal iPhone (iOS 12.4.1), and the issue is present for me.

Also, the one Android user I've asked does not experience this issue.

Are there issues with earlier versions of iOS and mobile css styles?

Answer (score 0):

iOS styles buttons by default. Perhaps the issue originates from there.
To overwrite that you can use this CSS:

```
button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
}
```